# chai-webdriver (node) ... describe is not a function

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, chai

I keep getting the error that describe is not a function.
How can I fix this

```
// Require chai.js expect module for assertions
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
chai.use = require ('chai-as-promised')
// Application Server
var serverUri = '0.0.0.0:3000';

// Official selenium webdriver testing setup
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

describe('basic test', function () {
    var driver;
    before(function(){
        // Start of test use this
        driver = new webdriver.Builder().
        withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
        build();
        console.log("Selenium Webdriver Chrome Started");
    });

    after(function(){
        // End of test use this.
        driver.quit();
    });

    it('should be on correct page', function (done) {
        this.timeout(10000);
        driver.get(serverUri);
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
            expect(title).to.equal('Some String Here');
            done();
            console.log("Selenium Webdriver Chrome Shutdown");
        })
    });
});
```

the error I get after running this is :

> describe is not a function

Comment: Did you install mocha and run it with mocha?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to require mocha (assuming you installed it)..

Try adding

`const { describe, it, before, after } = require('mocha');`

Comment: all mocha's functions are setup by mocha, you don't need to `require` or `import them`